# Getting hue from UIColor yields wrong result

Tags: swift, rgb, uicolor

I'm doing the following in order to retrieve the `hue` from a `UIColor()`:

```
let rgbColour = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
var hue: CGFloat = 0
var saturation: CGFloat = 0
var brightness: CGFloat = 0
var alpha: CGFloat = 0
rgbColour.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha)

println("\(hue),\(saturation),\(brightness)")
```

**Output:**

`1.0,1.0,1.0`

According to this [link](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-converter-01.htm), I'm meant to be getting `0.0,1.0,1.0` for RGB (red) `1.0,0.0,0.0`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The range for the red/green/blue components is 0.0 .. 1.0, not 0.0 .. 255.0 !!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all the range of the red/green/blue components in `UIColor` is 0.0 .. 1.0,
not 0.0 .. 255.0, so you probably want

```
let rgbColour = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

But even then you get the output `1.0,1.0,1.0` and this is *correct*.
The hue component ranges from 0.0 to 1.0, which corresponds to the angle from 0º to 360º
in a color wheel (see for example [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)).

Therefore `hue = 0.0` and `hue = 1.0` describe an *identical* color.
If you need to normalize the hue component to the half-open interval
`0.0 <= hue < 1.0` then you could do that with

```
hue = fmod(hue, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 7):

To build on @Martin R's answer:

If you wanted to use HSB, you need to:

1. Divide the hue value by 360
2. Use decimals for the `Saturation` and `Brightness` values

So, say for example that Sketch is telling you the colour values in HSB are: Hue: 20, Saturation: 72 and Brightness: 96

In Xcode, create the colour as follows:

```
let myAwesomeColour = UIColor(hue: 20/360, saturation: 0.72, brightness: 0.96, alpha: 1.0)
```

Whether you use RGB or HSB is a matter of preference. The results are the same as far as Xcode is concerned, they both translate to a `UIColor`.

Comment: Put another way, you could say the second rule is to divide `Saturation` and `Brightness` by 100.

Comment: Yes, of course, but that's completely unnecessary when you can simply add a zero and dot before the number. I mean, you could also do: 72/100 but why would you?

Comment: as a more generic solution. if you have dynamic values in a variable, as opposed to constants, then dividing by 100 is a generalized expression of the rule.